# Constraint based rules engine

Tags: constraint, database-engine, exclusion-constraint

I am evaluating software systems which configure products that tout constraint based versus rules based engines.  Can someone explain (with maybe an example or two) to a non-expert what the difference is?  My guess is that a constraint based engine is rules defining relationships between objects, and rules based engines are more like the WHERE clause of a SQL language query.

Answer (score 1):

Constraints will basically allow you to [enforce data integrity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190765%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - limiting the values that may be inserted into a column and there by enforcing business rules. The database engine (SQL Server) will automatically enforce integrity of a database based on the constraints defined 
e.g. NOT NULL, CHECK constraints, UNIQUE constraints,  PRIMARY KEY constraints, FOREIGN KEY Constraints, etc.

For Rule Engine,

> A rules engine is a schedule based data validity application that typically runs as a meta-layer on top of an OLTP application. It fires a set of queries (defined as rules) which determine whether the underlying data elements comply with a specific rule’s definition. The compliance to the rule is then recorded indicating a pass or fail.

I will just point you to some Microsoft articles and other useful links (as I am not a pro in this area).

- [Building a Rule Engine with SQL Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964135%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)
- [Choosing a Rules Engine Design](http://sqlserverplanet.com/design/types-of-rules-engines)
- [Creating a Rules Engine](http://sqlserverplanet.com/design/creating-a-rules-engine)